# Python enumerating or something else?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, enumerate

I am starting with a json object that follows this example:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://www.stackoverflow_greatquestions.com",
    "pages": 1
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com",
    "pages": 3
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is print the urls equal to the number of pages which I've done doing this:

```
url_list = []
for x in json:
    for y in range(x['pages']):
        url_list.append(x['url'])
```

I'm almost there, this is doing what I asked and printing out the urls, but I also want to number the output based on the value of pages.

So my end result would look like this:

```
"https://www.stackoverflow_greatquestions.com", 1,
"https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com", 1,
"https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com", 2,
"https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com", 3
```

I feel like enumerate would be useful here, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to implement it. All I can do is number the whole list, which as you can see from above is not what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thank you in advance,
Brian

Comment: `url_list.append((x['url'], y))`…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way. Nothing fancy, just a `for` loop and a `range` dependent on the `'pages'` key.

```
>>> data = [ 
...:   { 
...:     "url": "https://www.stackoverflow_greatquestions.com", 
...:     "pages": 1 
...:   }, 
...:   { 
...:     "url": "https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com", 
...:     "pages": 3 
...:   } 
...: ]                                                                                                                        
>>>                                                                                                                           
>>> for d in data: 
...:     for i in range(1, d['pages'] + 1): 
...:         print(d['url'], i) 
...:                                                                                                                          
https://www.stackoverflow_greatquestions.com 1
https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com 1
https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com 2
https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com 3
```

edit - building a list:

```
>>> result = [(d['url'], i) for d in data for i in range(1, d['pages'] + 1)]                                                  
>>> result                                                                                                                    
[('https://www.stackoverflow_greatquestions.com', 1),
 ('https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com', 1),
 ('https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com', 2),
 ('https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine:

```
url_list = []
for x in json:
    for y in range(x['pages']):
        url_list.append(x['url']+', '+str(y+1))
print(url_list)
```

***Output***

```
['https://www.stackoverflow_greatquestions.com, 1', 'https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com, 1', 'https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com, 2', 'https://www.stackoverflow_not-so-greatquestions.com, 3']
```

Comment: Thank you this also works, both methods have been noted and I appreciate all the help.